# How to find and replace a subview from UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview to which I have added 4 subviews at ViewDidLoad, now during app usage on an event I want to replace one of the subview with a new view.

I am trying to add tag to subview and find it and replace but the tag seems to be not found. Also not able to find a correct way to replace a view

```
let subViews = self.scrollView.subviews
for subview in subViews{
    if subview.tag == 1000 {
        let tempView = subview
        tempView = newView
    }
}
```

I am sure above code isn't right , here code never enters inside the 'if' and when i see all the subviews in debug area i dont see the tag as well.

code from ViewDidLoad

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        self.overLeftVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "settingViewController")
        self.leftVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "giftCardListViewController")
        self.middleVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "redeemViewController")
        self.rightVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeViewController")
        self.overRightVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ticketListViewController")

        let isShowBotView = self.config.getValue("isSystemGenerated", fromStore: "settings") as! Bool

        if isShowBotView == true {
            self.nextOfOverRightVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatViewController")
        }
        else {
            self.nextOfOverRightVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tileMainViewController")
        }

        self.nextOfOverRightVc.view.tag = 1000



            addChildViewController(overLeftVc)
            addChildViewController(leftVc)
            addChildViewController(middleVertScrollVc)
            addChildViewController(nextOfOverRightVc)
          //  addChildViewController(tileMainRightVc)

            scrollView.addSubview(overLeftVc.view)
            scrollView.addSubview(leftVc.view)
            scrollView.addSubview(middleVertScrollVc.view)
            scrollView.addSubview(nextOfOverRightVc.view)
```

Comment: How do you give the tag to the subview?

Comment: @ViktorSimkó view.tag = 1000

Comment: Can you also share the code in `viewDidLoad` where you create the scroll view and add the subviews to it?

Comment: @ViktorSimkó please check

Comment: It is silly to say `for subview in subViews{if subview.tag == 1000 {` because that is what saying `viewWithTag` already does for you.

Comment: Also, your code is deficient. You are saying `addChildViewController` and `addSubview` but you are neglecting to say `didMove(toParentViewController:)`.

Comment: All you have to do is save the zposition of the subview to be replaced, to remove the subview, to add a new subview, to change its zposition.

Comment: @ElTomato can you demo with a code fragment ?

Answer (score 1):

save the subview's frame in a variable  , remove that subview and insert a new subview at that Frame

```
for subview in subViews{
if subview.tag == 1000 {
    self.frameOfViewToBeReplaced = subview.frame
    subview.removeFromSuperView()
     }
 }
 let newView = UIView(frame : self.frameOfViewToBeReplaced)
```